# Recursive parsing using Java cup

Tags: java, parsing, dsl

I am working on a Domain Specific Language using Java cup and JLex. My language implements a java-like import system.

Example:

```
package p;

import module2;

module module1 {
    ...
}
```

Of course I want to parse module2 before parsing module1. Until now, I have something like:

```
CompilationUnit module1 = (CompilationUnit) parser.parse().value;

for(Import _import : module1.getImports())
    parse(_import.getPath())
```

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Why make this hard?   Parse the source file, build an AST, and then come back to handle symbol table issues.

Comment: My AST is the class CompilationUnit, but I would like to verify calls to module2 from module1. What I do not know how to do is while parsing module1 (the first one) how to verify calls to imported modules.

Comment: You can tangle checking into parsing, but that will just make your parser unnecessarily complicated.  I'm suggesting you let the parser do what it does best:  parse (and build your AST), and then do the checking after you have the entire tree.   The checks you will do won't change conceptually, but they'll be isolated and easier to write as a consequence.